# Разделители групп разрядов

Tags: c++, c++14

В С++14 добавили возможность разделять группы разрядов в числах. Как этим пользоваться? Не может ли это сломать существующий код?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Синтаксис

Новый синтаксис выглядит следующим образом:

```
100'200'300
0x1111'2222'aaaa'bbbbLL
1.022'303'004e+5
```

Апостроф (') можно добавлять между любыми двумя цифрами в числовых литералах (десятичных, шестнадцатеричных, восьмеричных, двоичных), целочисленных и с плавающей запятой.

Апостроф предназначен для повышения читаемости (см. [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C#.D0.A0.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BB.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BB.D1.8C_.D0.B3.D1.80.D1.83.D0.BF.D0.BF_.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B7.D1.80.D1.8F.D0.B4.D0.BE.D0.B2)) и никак не меняет значение числа, например литералы 123'456 и 12345 имеют одно значение.

#### Обратная совместимость

Поменялись границы числа, которые видит препроцессор. Правильный С++11 код может перестать компилироваться или выдавать другие результаты в С++14.

Например:

```
#define M(x, ...) __VA_ARGS__ // отбрасываем первый аргумент
int x[2] = { M(1'1,2'2) };
```

- В C++11 будет один аргумент `1 '1,2' 2` состоящий из трех токенов, массив будет инициализирован `= {};`.
- В C++14 будет два аргумента `1'1` и `2'2`, массив будет инициализирован `= { 2'2 };`.

Comment: Перестал наблюдать за С++ после 11 версии. Радует, что наконец-то реализовали. Вопрос - почему именно апостроф? Видел в других языках подобную фичу - там обычно нижнее подчеркивание использовалось. Да и непривычно как-то видеть апостроф - вон, даже подсветка с ума сходит.

Comment: Точно, я и забыл про них. Спасибо.

Comment: @Abyx, для чего нужен подобный синтаксис? Можно какой-нибудь простенький пример, где его использовать удобнее?